# subprocess.Popen : how to pass a list as argument

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I just need a hint on how to do things properly.

Say I have a script called script.py which uses a list of names as argument ["name1", "name2", etc. ].

I want to call this script from another script using the subprocess module. So what I would like to do is the following :

```
myList = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
subprocess.Popen(["python", "script.py", myList])
```

Of course that doesn't work because the subprocess.Popen method requires a list of strings as arguments.
So I considered doing the following :

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "script.py", str(myList)])
```

Now the process starts but it doesn't work because it has a string as argument and not a list. How should I fix that properly?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Concatenate them using `+` operator.

```
myList = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
subprocess.Popen(["python", "script.py"] + myList)
```

BTW, if you want use same python program, replace `"python"` with `sys.executable`.

Comment: or `.extend()` it if you are unsure about the type of the additional arguments.

Comment: @NiklasR, or `+ list(myList)`

Comment: `extend` is only useful if you modify a named list prior to the call. `subprocess.Popen(["python", "script.py"].extend(myList))` would pass `None` (the return value of `extend`) as the first and only argument to `Popen()`.

Comment: @falsetru, can we pass a new parameter (just like we pass to a function) from previous process to the new sub-process?

Comment: @user5319825, Yes, as you can see in the code in the answer. The sub-process can receive those command line parameters using [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Comment: I meant to pass an argument from the process which is executing to the process which is yet to start after a while (obviously to the next coming process)

Comment: @user5319825, I don't get it. Please post a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the quick answer falsetru. It doesn't work directly but I understand how to do.
You're suggestion is equivalent to doing :

```
subprocess.Popen(["Python","script.py","name1","name2","name3"])
```

Where I have 3 arguments that are the strings contained in my original list.

All I need to do in my script.py file is to build a new list from each argument received by doing the following :

```
myList = sys.argv[1:]
```

myList is now the same than the one I had initially!

```
["name1","name2","name3"]
```

Don't know why I didn't think about it earlier!

Comment: best way that worked for me was to use the `extend` to add more elements into the list. The `extend` came in handy as i have still to decide what to add into the list before calling `subprocess.Popen()`

Comment: thanks... place myList = sys.argv[1:] after  if __name__ == '__main__':