# Imagemagick convert command: set delay time for the last frame

Tags: imagemagick

I have some  .png files named '_tmp*.png' and I want to convert them into a gif file by the convert command with imagemagick. So i could use

```
convert -delay 20 _tmp*.png result.gif
```

However I want the last frame to hold for a while on screen so that one can see the ending of the animation more clearly. Say, I want the last frame to last for 3 seconds while keeping the delay time for the other frames not changed. I studied the document for the convert command but it seems it does not have such a choice.

So how can I do this with the convert command?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
convert -delay 40 {1..9}.png -delay 300 10.png -delay 40 {11..14}.png animated.gif
```

[image]

Basically, you set the delay **just before** the image you want it to affect and it stays set until you change it.

If you want to set a variable delay, so that the first (i.e. black here) and the last frame (i.e. yellow here) are displayed longer, you can do this:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:black xc:red xc:lime xc:blue xc:cyan xc:magenta xc:yellow -set delay '%[fx:t==(n-1) || t==0 ? 400 : 40]' result.gif
```

[image]

Comment: Serchell: Thanks!

Comment: But my images files are numbered like _tmp%03d.png where the numer ranges from 0 to N, N depends on the program's input, How can I do this in this case?

Comment: Assuming you know `N`, use `convert -delay 40 <N-1 images> -delay 300  <Nth image> result.gif`

Comment: I want to call convert command in a python script, so I have to write the convert command as a string, like

Comment: like `subprocess.call(['convert', '-delay', '40', '{1...N}.png'] ......)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Python, Maybe something like this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19683794/2836621 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30071309/2836621

Comment: I'm running this on Windows10. With this: `magick convert -delay 40 {1..11}.png -delay 3000 12.png logo.gif` I only get the last frame in the gif. Syntax `{1..11}.png` does not seem to work.

Comment: In your case you can also use `convert -delay 40 *.png -delay 2960 12.png logo.gif`.